# Does if-no-match need to be set programmatically in ajax request, if server sends Etag

Tags: ajax, jax-rs, etag, if-none-match

My question is pretty simple. Although while searching over, I have not found a simple satisfying answer.

> I am using Jquery ajax request to get the data from a server. Server
> hosts a rest API that sets the Etag and Cach-control headers to the `GET requests`. The Server also sets CORS headers to allow the `Etag`.
> The client of the Api is a browser web app. I am using Ajax request to call the Api. Here are the  response headers from server after a simple GET request:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=86400
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2015 13:23:41 GMT
Etag: "-783704964"
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Etag,Authorization
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
```

**All I want to know is:**

Do I need to manually collect the `Etag` from response headers sent from the server and attach an `if-no-match` header to ajax request?OR the Browser sends  it by-default in a `conditional get` request when it has an 'Etag'

> 

- I have done debugging over the network console in the browser and It
  seems the browser is doing the `conditional GET` automatically and
  sets the `if-no-match` header.
- if it is right, Suppose, I created a new resource, and then I called the get request. It gives me the past cached data for the first time. But when I reload the page, It gives the updated one. So I am confused that, If the dataset on the server-side has changed and it sends a different `Etag`, Why doesn't the browser get an updated data set from the server unless I have to reload

> 

- Also in case of pagination. Suppose I have a URL `/users?next=0`. `next is a query param` where the value for the `next` changes for every new request. Since each response will get its own 'Etag'. Will the browser store the 'Etag' based on request or it just stores the lastest `Etag` of the previous get request, irrespective of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have somehow figured out the solution myself:

The browser sends the `if-no-match` header itself when it sees url had the `e-tag` header on a previous `request`. Browser saves the `e-tag` with respect to that URL, so it does not matter how many requests with different URLs happen.

Also, a trick to force the browser to fetch a `conditional-get` to check the `e-tag`:

- `Set the max-age header to the lowest` (for me 60s works great)
- once the `cache` expires, thebrowser will send a `conditional-get` to check if the `expired cached resource` is valid. If the `if-no-match` header matches with `e-tag`. The server sends the response back with `304: Not-Modified` header. This means the expired cached resource is valid and can be used.

Comment: I am facing this same issue. I am not able to understand completely what you did to resolve it. My Issue is - 

I make an ajax request and send back ETag and Last-Modified in response header.
But whenever I refresh the page, if-none-match and if-modified-since request headers are not present.
Can you please help me in resolving this.

Comment: how are you calling the ajax request to:
API call ??
Does the server have appropriate max-age and etag tags set for response?